# Jaspersoft Studio - not realoading subreport content from server in preview

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

I'm having trouble with subreports in Jasper studio. Currently I'm working on template where I would like to add header / footer / maybe title as subreports. The reason is that I have around 100 reports where I want to add this "shared footer/header ... " so that if anything changes in future I would only have to change it in one file.

**About**

For example I have my main report that contains two subreports header / footer. When I upload all these reports to server and run main report, it works fine.

Let's say that I change text in header and I upload it to server and again run main report I can see changed text in header.

**Problem:**

Now when I work on this report locally and I hit **Preview** I always see some cached version of that subreport from very early stage when I was making this header subreport.

What I tried:

- added -clean to .exe (target)
- deleted folder in file:/C:/Users/..../AppData/Local/Temp/
- Project - Clean - Clean all project
- restarted PC

Subreport settings:

- Using cache : false
- Expression: "repo:/....."

So far I do not know, where could be the problem... why does the preview tab just do not update that subreport content. How can I remove that cache ?

Comment: I would guess this is not actually a cache problem, but instead the subreport jrxml has not been recompiled to .jasper (hence studio is using an old .japer, the subreports needs to be recompiled). The command is "build all", but studio can be a bit buggy, maybe try to also to view the subreport in preview (this should force the build of the subreport)

Comment: @PetterFriberg thank you for your message. What I do not understand is that I'm loading that subreport from server not locally so I guess that recompiling local file is no go but I tried it. How I managed to make it work is that I went to **repository explorer** in Jasper Studio I've located my "footer subreport" and I've clicked to that little arrow that opens all files for that report and I used **"Open in editor"** for **main_jrxml** file. When I compiled this file I was able to use newest version of this subreport in my report preview :)

Comment: Great consider to self answer your question, explaining what future users need to do do :)

Answer (score 1):

**My solution:**

How I managed to make it work is that I went to **repository explorer** in Jasper Studio I've located my "footer subreport" and I've clicked to that little arrow that opens all files for that report and I used **"Open in editor"** for **main_jrxml** file. When I compiled this file I was able to use newest version of this subreport in my **main report** preview :)